# Parse - Saving Object against an Object and saving a Collection

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my `Android Application`, I am trying to save an object called `Game` and I wish to save a `List` of `Player`. How would I do this? As far as I can see, the tutorials state that I can save primitive types or types which parse allows, e.g. `Number`, `String`, `Date` etc. But how would I save a `List<Player>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

`Player playerObject;
game.add("players", playerObject);`

OR

`List<Player> players;
game.addAll("players", players)`;

Comment: Thank you. I actually found what I was looking for on the Guide in parse.com.